# Phonegap serve on Ubuntu not syncing with iOS app

Tags: iphone, cordova, ubuntu, phonegap-plugins

So I am working on a phonegap project with a friend (who is running ubuntu) and there is an issue we are coming across when trying to view the project on the phonegap developer app on an iPhone. When we run `phonegap serve` everthing is working properly but when we try to connect to the port given by the terminal on the phone we are given an error:

`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/res/middleware/cordova/3.5.0/ios/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js'`

Anyone know what this means?

BTW, I am running `phonegap serve` on a Mac and it is working perfectly. We are using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. It seems this issue is caused by case sensitivity of the file system. It tried to access **inappbrowser.js** but it is called **InAppBrowser.js**. So you can work around the error with a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/res/middleware/cordova/3.5.0/ios/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/InAppBrowser.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/res/middleware/cordova/3.5.0/ios/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js
```